# Swift: How to programmatically change a label/view size depending on iPhone (eg. iPhone SE, iPhone 8)?

Tags: ios, iphone, size

Is it possible to programmatically change a label size or view size depending on which iPhone the user uses?

So for instance that I can detect in code what phone is used and change the width of a view or label depending on which phone is used (ie. bigger on an iPhone 8 and smaller on an iPhone SE)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, all the other answers are right, you need to code based on autolayouts so that your UI components fit dynamically. But, still, if you want to know the device size as you have mentioned in your question, then take a look at the screen size property, and calculate your UI components size accordingly. You can get the device screen size as:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

Now, based on how long or wide the screen is, you can decide your UI component's size.

Cheers,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

The concept you want to look into is called [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using AutoLayout in your code.

E.g: 
In the xib/storybaords, the left, right, top, bottom constraints if set to zero,  the view will always stick to all the four edges .

Reference Link: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html